# Julia Calling Python Function

Tags: python, julia, pycallgraph

I've been trying to call python functions from Julia using this code:

```
using PyCall
unshift!(PyVector(pyimport("sys")["path"]), "")
@pyimport testing
print(testing.add())
```

testing is in the same path.

the testing python file:

```
def add():
    return 5 + 5
```

I am getting this error from Julia though:

```
LoadError: PyError (ccall(@pysym(:PyImport_ImportModule), PyPtr, (Cstring,), 
name)) <class 'ImportError'> ImportError("No module named 'testing'",)

while loading C:\Users\Benjamin\AppData\Local\JuliaPro-0.6.0.1\test.jl, in expression starting on line 410
pyerr_check at exception.jl:56 [inlined]
pyerr_check at exception.jl:61 [inlined]
macro expansion at exception.jl:81 [inlined]
pyimport(::String) at PyCall.jl:370
include_string(::String, ::String) at loading.jl:515
include_string(::Module, ::String, ::String) at Compat.jl:577
(::Atom.##55#58{String,String})() at eval.jl:73
withpath(::Atom.##55#58{String,String}, ::String) at utils.jl:30
withpath(::Function, ::String) at eval.jl:38
macro expansion at eval.jl:71 [inlined]
(::Atom.##54#57{Dict{String,Any}})() at task.jl:80
```

How can I fix this?

Also how can I do this:
(Julia):

```
using PyCall
unshift!(PyVector(pyimport("sys")["path"]), "")
@pyimport testing
print(testing.add(5, 5))
```

(Python):

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me as you expect if I rename your `testing.py` file to something different, like `mytests.py`:

```
julia> using PyCall

julia> unshift!(PyVector(pyimport("sys")["path"]), "")
PyObject ['', … ]

julia> @pyimport mytests

julia> mytests.add(5,5)
10
```

I have a `testing` package in my site-packages folder, which may be causing the trouble:

```
julia> @pyimport testing

julia> testing.__path__
1-element Array{String,1}:
 "/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/testing"
```

Comment: I got it to work with a parameter-less function however with a function with a parameter it is giving me the error that it expects the function takes 0 positional argument but 1 was given.